# Is this pattern suitable for Core Data?

Tags: ios, core-data, database-design

The only databases I've worked with before are MySQL so the database design of CoreData is confusing me a little bit.

Briefly, the design consists of a many-to-many relationship between people and businesses. Many people can own one business. One person can own many businesses.

In this simplified design, there are 3 tables:

```
PERSON       BUSINESS      OWNED BUSINESS
------       --------      --------------
id           id            personID
name         name          businessID
email        website       acquisitionDate
```

The OwnedBusiness table is the one that's confusing me. In MySQL, this table is used to support many-to-many relationships. I understand that CoreData doesn't require this, however I have an extra field in OwnedBusiness: `acquisitionDate`.

---

Does the extra field, `acquisitionDate` warrant the use of the extra entity/table? If not, where would that field go?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

First, Core Data is not a database, full stop.

Core Data is an object graph management framework, your model in your application.

It *can* persist to disk in a database.  It can also persist as binary, XML and just about anything else.  It does not even *need* to persist.

Think about Core Data as an object graph only.  In your example you would have a `Person` entity, a `Business` entity and a `OwnedBusiness` entity.

The `OwnedBusiness` entity would have two relationships and one property.  You would not manage the foreign keys because Core Data handles that **if** you end up persisting to a database.  Otherwise they are object pointers.

Comment: Great thanks. Your last two paragraphs describe what I currently have in the model (the tables were just my written design); just needed someone to verify what I had was on the right track.

Comment: Keep the unique identifiers on Business and Person.  They are always helpful.

Answer (score 1):

So first of all, `CoreData` is not a relational `db` just to clear this out.

Second, I think you should have a quick look at `CoreData` documentation and since you are familiar with `MySql` it will be an easy reading and I think you will be kind of amazed by the extra features that `CoreData` provides.

Regarding the `many-to-many` relationship, `CoreData` support this relationship without the need of extra tables. Also the relationship are not based on `id`s, they are based directly on objects.

So in your case, you don't have to use the person `id` & business `id` to create the relationship, you can create the relationship in the `Relationship` section of your `xcdatamodel`, there you can set the relationship class (or Destination), an inverse to that relationship (useful thing) and of course the type of relationship (to-many, to-one).

So to answer your question, you can add it there depending on your business logic. As a short advice, pleas don't try to normalise the database as you would do on a normal MySql instance, you will loose lot of performance by normalising, this thing is often ignored by devs.

Comment: `don't try to normalise the database ... you will loose lot of performance by normalising` - Really? Do you have any documentation to back this up?

Comment: @JamesWebster Maybe I expressed a little harsh, the correct expression should be `don't over normalise` and yeah, check this post http://asciiwwdc.com/2013/sessions/211 and also you can watch the full wwdc session from 2013.

Comment: Because Core Data is an object graph first, "normal" database normalization is actually harmful to performance.  The pointers that danypata gave you will explain it in more detail.